# Bamboo Deployments using MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy, bamboo

I have created a CI with bamboo for a MVC Project. Build works fine but the problem is with the deployment using msdeploy. Below is the configuration of the deployment in Bamboo
[image: Deployment Configuration]

Problem is with the arguments send to msdeploy which looks like this:

```
-source:package='${bamboo.build.working.directory}\Artifacts\WebDeploy\webdeploy.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://my_web_app.cloudapp.net:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=web_app_name",userName="deploy_user_name",password="passowrd",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -allowUntrusted -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="web_app_name"
```

When this code is run in bamboo, i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unrecognized argument '"-setParam:name="IIS'. All arguments must begin with "-".
```

if  `-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="web_app_name"` is removed from the script deployent is done with success but in a wrong website (virtual directory under Default Web Site)

Any ideas on how this can be fixed without using a separate `.bat` file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with a similar issue about a month ago.  From everything I've seen, MSDeploy struggles to deal with arguments that have spaces in them.  As a result, "IIS Web Application Name" will give you trouble.  To overcome this, I excluded this argument and was able to achieve the same goal by including /p:Configuration=DeployIISAppPath="Default Web Site/web_app_name" in the MSBuild command line used to build the deployment package.